Проблема с костями в блендер
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XIG-F80NtTtguAWJuqyf9LXG655p0F60/view?usp=sharing
Здравствуйте, скачал модель из Интернета(для анимирования) и столкнулся с проблемой. При добавлении кости к объекту, сам объект удаляется. Кость привязываю по алгоритму Parent ->With automatic Wieght. Как можно исправить данную проблему? Прикрепил файл, если кому-то удобнее так.
()

Форум blender, там вопросы по блендер, удачи!

@NikolaiVorobiev у нас "есть вопросы по blender дома", см. [tag:blender]. Не такая популярная тема, но все же есть смысл и тут задавать вопросы по нему.

@insolor, Ну просто SO на английском против блендера у сетя, я ответил по аналогии

@NikolaiVorobiev, ну я немного иронизирую. Тут вопросы по blender вроде бы явное не запрещены, и никто особо не против них, хотя не понятно как прикрепленная ссылка на гугл драйв соответствует правилу "минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого" примера в самом вопросе. Тут скорее имело бы смысл задавать вопрос, если он по blender api. Но может и на такой вопрос кто-то ответит.
